# Checking for undefined props

Tags: react-native

I am passing a prop into my component to style up my border:

```
 <ArrowButton text="xxxx" bottom link="http://www.xxx.co.uk" />
```

When I try and use the prop to style up my child component:

```
 borderTopWidth: typeof bottom === "undefined" ? 2 : 0,
 borderBottomWidth: typeof bottom === "undefined" ? 0 : 2,
```

I can neve get the `bottomBorder` to show. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of bottom? I would assume passing it in like that might give it a value? You could probably check like: `bottom == null` instead of the typeof like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `"undefined"` which means it is actually checking for the **string** undefined.

You can simply do

```js
// if bottom is a boolean
borderTopWidth: bottom ? 0 : 2,
borderBottomWidth: bottom ? 2 : 0,
```